# how to fix MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

When ever I tried to connect even changing the localhost to 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0 keep the same.
I have tired adding  family: 4 and
`{ useNewUrlParser: true,  useUnifiedTopology: true, }`

And sometimes it takes hours to finsih loading and endup showing the same error
` G:\Coding Acadamy\js\MongoD\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:791
err = new ServerSelectionError();
^

```
     MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
      at _handleConnectionErrors (G:\Coding    
   Acadamy\js\MongoD\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:791:11)
   at NativeConnection.openUri (G:\Coding      
     Acadamy\js\MongoD\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:766:11) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
   type: 'Unknown',
   servers: Map(1) {
   'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
    address: 'localhost:27017',
      type: 'Unknown',
    hosts: [],
      passives: [],
     arbiters: [],
    tags: {},
    minWireVersion: 0,
    maxWireVersion: 0,
    roundTripTime: -1,
    lastUpdateTime: 1952326,
    lastWriteDate: 0,
    error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
        at connectionFailureError (G:\Coding   
     Acadamy\js\MongoD\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\
     connect.js:370:20)
        at Socket.<anonymous> (G:\Coding   
      Acadamy\js\MongoD\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\conn
      ect.js:293:22)
        at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
        at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
        at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
        at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
      cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
          at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
        errno: -4078,
        code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
        syscall: 'connect',
        address: '::1',
        port: 27017
      },
      [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
    },
    topologyVersion: null,
    setName: null,
    setVersion: null,
    electionId: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    primary: null,
    me: null,
    '$clusterTime': null
    }
  },
   stale: false,
  compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
  localThresholdMS: 15,
  setName: null,
   maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
   logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
    },
  code: undefined
   }

   Node.js v18.16.0`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `mongodb://localhost:27017`, not `localhost:27017`. Hope this helps!

---

If this helped, remember to press the grey checkmark next to this answer!